# Log transformation-ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, valueerror, normal-distribution

The data of some columns don't follow normal distribution and I wanted to normalize them by using log transformation.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14,6))
#1
sns.distplot(train_df['MasVnrArea'], fit=stats.norm, ax=ax[0])
ax[0].set_title('Before Normalization')

#2
train_df['MasVnrArea'] = np.log(train_df['MasVnrArea'])
ax[1].set_title('After Normalization')
sns.distplot(train_df['MasVnrArea'], fit=stats.norm, ax=ax[1])
```

Part `#1` works fine, but when it comes to part `#2` it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I already check if there was a NaN value in this column, but there was nothing. So what's the problem with it?

Comment: Difficult to debug as we don't have access to your data. Can you post a representative dataset? Otherwise it is hard to help.

Comment: One of the Kaggle's dataset. [house price](https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When** did you check if there are NaN values?

Did you check if `train_df['MasVnrArea']` have values equal or under 0?
If there are values equal to or under 0, the log return NaN and the plot in the next line will throw the error.

- **Check again if there are NaN values after the log calculation.**

**Example** from [Using numpy.log() on 0](https://www.journaldev.com/46723/numpy-log-in-python)

```
import numpy as np 
print(np.log(0))
```

**Output:**

```
-inf 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
```

**Explanation:**

The logarithm of zero is not defined. It’s not a real number, because you can never get zero by raising anything to the power of anything else.

Comment: It has values equal 0, but not under 0. And yeah I checked if there are NaN values after transformation and there were non of them.

Comment: That's the problem. log of 0 is not defined.

Comment: Sometimes in numpy.log it returns "-inf".

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. So It can't be normalized by log transformation.